# Cannot paste from Office 2007 into p:editor

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

You cannot paste from Office 2007 into the primefaces editor control.  When you paste in and press Save, the content is cleared out and nothing is persisted.  In fact when you paste in, and then switch to "source view" in the control, no source is visible other than `<p>&nbsp;</p>`.  Then when you switch back out of "source view", the content has gone.

It appears to paste into the control OK, but obviously has not.

If you paste into Lync 2010 for example (in a chat box) and then copy and paste from there, it works OK and pastes in.  There must be something in the transfer or the HTML code coming from Office 2007 which kills the p:Editor.

It is critical for our app that users are able to paste notes in, which they may have received from customers via email.  I can't ask corporate IS to upgrade the entire companies version of Office unfortunately.

Has anyone experienced this issue, or does anyone have any solutions for this.  Perhaps an alternative rich text editor or some knowledge of whats "odd" about Office 2007 HTML formatting?

Comment: PrimeFaces uses under the covers CLEditor. You may get better help if you ask a question specifically about that instead of whoever has generated the CLEditor markup (JSF/PrimeFaces). Once you get the answer, report it as an issue to PrimeFaces guys so that they may integrate the fix in the component generating the CLEditor output.

Comment: Hi,  Seems that when I try the raw CLEditor - the source is being recognised after a paste, unlike PrimeFaces where the source does not seem to reflect at all the visible content pasted in.

Comment: I'd report it to PF guys. Perhaps they used an older version or have introduced some bugs.

Comment: I have posted on PF forum, now trying to work out how to use a native CLEditor and integrate it into JSF.

Answer (score 1):

yes you are right there are some special characters which javascript is not able to parse. You can try some extra wrapper method which removes these special characters

Comment: any advice on how I can work out which characters are causing the problems?

Answer (score 0):

I switched to using the primefaces extensions pe:ckEditor and this is working for me now as expected.

Regards

i

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, the wrapper method has to convert the Iframe contents to BASE64 encoding. Use window.atob() and window.btoa() for BASE64 conversions.